# How to set a different default font for every language?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, fonts

How does Chrome decide which font to use for every Unicode character? For example, let's say I have 4 Hebrew fonts, 5 Hindi fonts and 6 Arabic fonts. Which font will be used to display Hebrew, Arabic and Hindi characters by default? Do I have control over that? In the Chrome setting I noticed I can only choose ONE default font, so which fonts are being chosen for other languages?

Answer (score 0):

i think you must use some javascript to detect the browser language and load a different css on the DOM loading. I don't see any other 'native' solution.